# How could I redefine a new type for subclass

Tags: php, inheritance

I'm trying to represent some entity.

- LineProduct A line holding a quantity of product and a Product entity
- LineProductBlank A line holding a quantity of product and a ProductBlank entity
- Product Entity is a real life product
- ProductBlank Entity is some product that a user want to create which contain ONLY a name

See this scheme for better understand :

[image]

So a quantity_line_product is related to a concret real life product (Product entity) or to a user Blank product (ProductBlank entity)

```
/**
 * A concret line holding a Product entity
 */
class LineProduct {
   private ?QuantityLineProduct $quantityLineProduct;

   public function getQuantityLineProduct(): ?QuantityLineProduct{
        ...
   }
   // ...Setter...
}

abstract class QuantityLineProduct{
    private ?int $id = null;
    private ?int $quantity;
   
   /**
     * @return ProductBase|null
     */
    public abstract function getProduct(): ?ProductBase;

    /**
     * @param ProductBase|null $product
     * @return $this
     */
    public abstract function setProduct(?ProductBase $product): self;
}

/**
 *  This entity holding relation between a concrete real life Product entity and a LineProduct.
 */
class QuantityLineProductProduct extends QuantityLineProduct{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Product::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private ?Product $product;
     
    public function getProduct(): ?Product{
        // ... Return a Product entity ...
    }
    public function setProduct(?Product $product): self{
       // ... Set a Product entity ...
    }
}

/**
 *  This entity holding relation between a user specific product ProductBlank entity and a LineProduct.
 */
class QuantityLineProductProduct extends QuantityLineProduct{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=ProductBlank::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private ?ProductBlank $product;
     
    public function getProduct(): ?ProductBlank{
        // ... Return a Product entity ...
    }
    public function setProduct(?ProductBlank $product): self{
       // ... Set a Product entity ...
    }
}
```

It look perfectly logic, but this is not working at all because PHP prevent to redefine type from a superclass.

The error is :

> Declaration of QuantityLineProductBlank::setProduct must be compatible
> with QuantityLineProduct::setProduct

I've understand the error. I'm looking for a way to do this properly. I need to be able to know which kind of object is located in which kind of subclass.

I want to be able to do :

```
$a = new QuantityLineProductProduct(); // Represent the relation between a Product and a LineProduct.

$a->getProduct()->getAnyMethodInsideProductEntity();
```

Actually this is not possible because `ProductBase` is the type of the property returned by `getProduct()`. So I need to do this :

```
$a = new QuantityLineProductProduct(); // Represent the relation between a Product and a LineProduct.

$product = $a->getProduct();

if($product instanceof Product){
   $product->getAnyMethodInsideProductEntity(); // Now this is working because we know the type of product
}
```

But I really don't want to have to do this everytime I need to acces any function of a product object.

Let's imagine a view where I want to display every data from a product inside a QuantityProductLine.

I'll need to check the type of the product everytime before I want to access all of its data.

Comment: I precise that I know this is not possible in PHP to redefine a method signature but so what could I do ? How could I make this work fine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are running into is the concept of "covariance and contravariance". This is not specific to PHP, it's a fundamental notion in OOP and other type systems.

Put simply, in order for a sub-type to meet the contract of its parent, it must:

- Accept all the inputs that its parent accepts, according to the contract.
- Never return a value that its parent would not return, according to the contract.

It however may:

- Accept *additional* inputs that its parent would not accept (contravariance of input).
- Promise to return a *smaller range* of values than its parent (covariance of output).

The contract of `QuantityLineProduct` says that the `setProduct` method accepts any `ProductBase`, so a sub-class can't restrict that contract further. Otherwise, you can't safely write code like this:

```php
function foo(QuantityLineProduct $qlp) {
   $qlp->setProduct(new Product); // would fail if $qlp was the "wrong" sub-type!
}
```

I think the modelling error here is in treating `QuantityLineProduct` as a mutable object, with the input defined as part of the interface. If you instead model it as immutable, with the input as part of a sub-class specific constructor, the model works:

```php
abstract class QuantityLineProductBase {
   /**
    * Contract: will always return some kind of ProductBase
    */
   abstract public function getProduct(): ProductBase;
}

class QuantityLineProductProduct extends QuantityLineProductBase {
   private Product $product;

   /**
    * Constructor doesn't need to obey substitution principles
    */
   public function __construct(Product $product) {
      $this->product = $product;
   }

   /**
    * Covariance of output; no violation
    */
   public function getProduct(): Product {
      return $this->product;
   }
}

class QuantityLineProductBlank extends QuantityLineProductBase {
   private ProductBlank $product;

   /**
    * Constructor accepting a different type; no violation
    */
   public function __construct(ProductBlank $product) {
      $this->product = $product;
   }
   /**
    * Covariance of output; no violation
    */
   public function getProduct(): ProductBlank {
      return $this->product;
   }
}
```

You can now create the container that's appropriate for each use case, and use it safely.

You also get all the benefits of immutable (or less mutable) objects: code is easier to reason about when actions can't have side effects on other parts of the program.

You might also want to have a factory method / object, which takes any `ProductBase` and creates either `QuantityLineProductProduct` or `QuantityLineProductBlank` as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm sorry I forgot ``extends`` key word while writing my question. But regarding the scheme I give of course ``QuantityLineProductProduct`` or ``QuantityLineProductBlank`` extends a base abstract class which is ``QuantityLineProduct``. Your answer fail in the same error as mine : ``Declaration of QuantityLineProductProduct::getProduct(): Product must be compatible with QuantityLineProductBase::getProduct(): ProductBase``.

I'll edit my question just to add the ``extends``

Comment: I mean the error that I got ``Declaration of QuantityLineProductBlank::setProduct must be compatible with QuantityLineProduct::setProduct`` already suggest itself that ``QuantityLineProductBlank`` extends ``QuantityLineProduct``.

Comment: There are some limitations on PHP's ability to detect safe covariance when classes are autoloaded (because it doesn't know all the class definitions in advance), but the above code compiles fine if placed all in one file: https://3v4l.org/aVrWS While you're right that your code example forgot the `extends` (always test examples before you post them!) that didn't change anything about my answer, which if you read closely is about how to remove the `setProduct` method.

Comment: While this solution is not perfect because I can't use ``getProduct()`` from a random ``QuantityLineProduct`` object. I have to use ``instanceof`` every time I watch an items inside a collection of entity. But well that's better than before

Comment: I think this is the best solution

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE I don't follow; if you have any instance of `QuantityLineProductBase`, you can call `getProduct` on it and be guaranteed some instance of `ProductBase`. That's the whole point of polymorphism and contracts: the signature of the method tells you what you can expect, and sub-classes can't break that expectation.

Comment: Yes that's right I can't expect more. I hope this model is fine.